# ComboBoxItem doesn't display

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a style for ComboBox in the Popup. Here is the 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEemR.png) of my ComboBoxItem 
 **Here is a code:**

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}"  
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                      Width ="549"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      ClickMode="Press"/>
                        <Popup Name="Popup"
                               IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                               AllowsTransparency="True" 
                               Focusable="False"
                               PopupAnimation="Fade" 
                               VerticalOffset="10">
                            <Grid Name="DropDown"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" CornerRadius="18"/>
                                <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"  Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Styles for ToggleButton and ComboBoxItems:**

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="520"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" Background="White" />
                        <Path Data="M12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2M7,10L12,15L17,10H7Z" 
                              Fill="#FF16CD1C" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#E1E1E1" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


 <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsInDesignMode}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="18"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Border.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ComboBoxItem.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                        To="#E1E1E1"
                                        Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ComboBoxItem.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                        FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                                        To="#FFFFFF"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Border.Triggers>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When I choose any item from the List, it doesn't display.Just a white space. I tried to Bind SelectionBoxItem, but it doesn't work.
 I will be so happy if I get answer.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Template doesn't contain ContentPresenter, where to show selected item. It should be here:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                      Width="549"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}"  
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  ClickMode="Press"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"/>
                        <Popup Name="Popup"...
```

Also, I'm not really sure your code works as in Combobox's Style Setter there is an IsSelected property. And it has value, that should be assigned to ItemContainerStyle property:

```
 <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"/>
```

Also, I would recommend you not to use DynamicResource, if it is not so valuable for you. Use StaticResource instead.

Comment: Sorry, now I've tested my solution and figured out, that ContentPresenter should be in combobox template. It should work fine now. I've edited my answer. Try it and let me know, please.